# Dealing with Lists in R - combine two data frames and calculate values with mismatched sizes

Tags: r, list, dataframe, dplyr, apply

I have two `data.frame` in R that I need to calculate values based on a subset of columns in each of the two dataframes.

This is geolocated data, so I've been using `geosphere` to do some of the calculations. These are the two dataframes.  `dat1` contains just a list of **lat/long** coordinates for random data points on the surface of the Earth. `dat2` is a set of objects on Earth with a **lat/long** location and a **speed/size** associated with them.

```
library(geosphere)
set.seed(1)
dat1 <- data.frame( long = runif( n = 10, min = -180, max = 180 ),
                lat = runif( n = 10, min = -90, max = 90 ) )

dat2 <- data.frame( long = runif( n = 10, min = -180, max = 180 ),
                lat = runif( n = 10, min = -90, max = 90 ),
                size = runif( n = 10, min = 0, max = 1500 ),
                speed = rnorm( n = 10, mean = 100, sd = 30 ) )
```

I need to calculate the distance from each point in `dat1` to all of the objects in `dat2`, while also keeping the **size** and **speed** data.  I've been doing this by creating a list of all the `dat1` locations:

```
list.dat1   <- split( dat1, 1:nrow( dat1 ) )
```

And using a double `for` loop (bad form in R, I know), but it works okay.

```
for( i in 1:length( list.dat1 ) ){
  for( j in 1:nrow( dat2 ) ) {
two.points = matrix( c( dat2[ j, 'long'], dat2[j,'lat'], # create matrix 
           dat1[ i, 'long' ], dat1[ i,'lat' ] ), # column 1 and 2 is long lat 
           nrow = 2, ncol = 2, byrow = T )     # make a matrix of these two locations

    ## now add the data from the objects
    list.dat1[[i]][j,3] = dat2[ j, 'long' ]  # add impactor long
    list.dat1[[i]][j,4] = dat2[ j, 'lat' ]  # add impactor lat

    ## calculate distance
    list.dat1[[i]][j,5] = distGeo( two.points )[1] / 1000  # distance kilometers
    list.dat1[[i]][j,6] = dat2[ j, 'size' ]   # add size of object
    list.dat1[[i]][j,7] = dat2[ j, 'speed' ]  # add speed of object
  }
}
```

Then I just rename columns

```
for( i in 1:length( list.dat1) ) {
   colnames( list.dat1[[i]]) = c( "point.long", "point.lat", 
                                      "object.long", "object.lat",
                                      "distance.to.object", "object.size", 
                                      "object.speed" )
}
```

This is horribly inefficient as `dat1` has 1000 rows and `dat2` has anywhere from 100 to 100,000 rows.

I was thinking I could make `list.dat1` a list of dataframes with length `nrow(dat2)` but I'm not sure how to accomplish that.

Then I could simply `cbind` the `dat2` data into each list element in `list.dat1` using `lapply`?

Then, finally, do the `distGeo()` calculation on each row of each list?

I'm still learning how to efficiently use R lists and `apply()` suite functions, so any help on making this more efficient would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new dataframe that creates all combinations of points in dat1 and dat2 with `tidyr::crossing` and then call the `distGeo` function on the resulting dataframe.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dat1 %>% 

    # rename dat1 long,lat to distinguish between dat1,dat2
    rename(dat1_long = long, dat1_lat = lat) %>% 

    # create all combinations
    tidyr::crossing(dat2) %>%

    # compute the distance between points 
    mutate(dist = distGeo(p1 = cbind(dat1_long, dat1_lat), 
                          p2 = cbind(long, lat)))
```

Comment: This is a nice output @AdroMine!  Do you have any recommendations for decreasing the size of the memory requirements for this approach?  When my `dat1` file has 10,000 rows and `dat2` has 300k rows, I use up the memory very quickly. For instance, removing some of the columns (if I don't need `speed`), or breaking `dat2` into separate files and recombining later?

Comment: Breaking up dat2 should be the way to go. Since you have to compute distance between each point in dat1 with each point in dat2, so given their sizes you would need to store 3 billion pair distances, so that will always take up memory.

Comment: You could use `sf::st_distance()` to calculate a distance matrix of the two point vectors which will probably be more memory efficient than storing the distance data in a data frame with all the other data, but there is no way around the fact that the memory requirement grows exponentially with the number of points

Answer (score 2):

Here is a data.table approach which might help with your large datasets:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(dat1)[, `:=`(d1_id=.I, id=1)]
setDT(dat2)[, `:=`(d2_id=.I, id=1)]
dat1[dat2,on=.(id),allow.cartesian=T] %>% 
.[, dist:=distGeo(cbind(long,lat), cbind(i.long,i.lat))] %>% 
.[,.(d1_id, long, lat, d2_id, size, speed, dist)]
```

Output: (first six rows)

```
     d1_id       long         lat d2_id      size     speed     dist
  1:     1  -84.41688 -52.9245765     1 1231.4194  98.31614 11610004
  2:     2  -46.03540 -58.2197845     1 1231.4194  98.31614 12903703
  3:     3   26.22721  33.6641124     1 1231.4194  98.31614 13868897
  4:     4  146.95480 -20.8613307     1 1231.4194  98.31614  2208091
  5:     5 -107.39450  48.5714556     1 1231.4194  98.31614 10727196
  6:     6  143.42029  -0.4141364     1 1231.4194  98.31614  1487321
```